# Can we get Windows time and apply condition on it to Echo a message?

Tags: php, javascript, datetime, if-statement, timestamp

i was searching for doing an interesting thing (at least for me). I Want to get the windows time in php and depending upon the time, I want to `echo` some message like

```
if(currentTime>09am OR currentTime<8pm){
echo " Have a Good day Dear";
}
else{
echo "Good Evening";
}
```

searching through the php manual and searching on the Google gave me many functions that can set time zone, or tell you the difference between two time intervals. But I can't see even a single function Like that.

Is it possible to in PHP? or it should be done in some other language like JavaScript? Note that only Hours and minutes are needed for the condition

How can I code it? any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
$min = strtotime('9:00 AM');
$max = strtotime('8:00 PM');
$currentTime = time();

if ( currentTime > $min || currentTime < $max ) {
  echo "Have a Good day Dear";
} else{
  echo "Good Evening";
}
```

Comment: Should be `$currentTime > $min && $currentTime < $max`